# Implementation of __iadd__ in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have defined a fraction class and am implementing shorthand addition as follows

```
def __iadd__(self,f2):
    self.num=(self.num*f2.den+f2.num*self.den)
    self.den=self.den*f2.den
    return (self.num,self.den)
a=fraction(3,-15)
b=fraction(40,15)
print a+=b
```

The compiler says the program  has a syntax error and and the `=` sign is highlighted. Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong. The python version is 2.7

Comment: You cannot print a statement(`a += b`). A statement has no value in Python.

Comment: `print a+=b` ? can you print this? I don't think

Comment: Also you may want to return `self`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve my issue.I understand that a+=b is (a=a+b) , but I thought that I would be able to make my function return the output like a + b does(I can print a+b since it is not a statement ).So then a+=b is a statement and not a operator representing (a=a+b)?